# How to iteterate over set of std classes on a variable with n depth to pick up a certain member propery ?

Tags: php

I have following data structure with a set of standard classes (that span over 'n'th depth), i need to select all the sub-addresses std classes (even if they are as subclass of subclass. How do i iterate this through php code ?

```
object(AddressSearchResponse)[96]
  public 'primaryAddress' => 
    object(gPrimaryAddress)[95]
      public 'postcode' => string '2140' (length=4)
      public 'state' => string 'NSW' (length=3)
      public 'locality' => string 'HOMEBUSH WEST' (length=13)
      public 'streetName' => string 'HAMPSTEAD' (length=9)
      public 'streetType' => string 'RD' (length=2)
      public 'addressSummary' => 
        object(stdClass)[94]
          public 'addressId' => string '2417756' (length=9)
          public 'confirmedFlag' => string 'Y' (length=1)
          public 'propertyNumberFrom' => int 35
          public 'propertyNumberTo' => int 37
          public 'ESA' => string 'HOME' (length=4)
          public 'subAddress' => 
            object(stdClass)[93]
              public 'addressId' => string '2628600' (length=9)
              public 'parentAddressId' => string '2417756' (length=9)
              public 'confirmedFlag' => string 'Y' (length=1)
              public 'subAddressType' => string 'Building' (length=8)
              public 'subAddressNumberFrom' => string '1' (length=1)
              public 'subAddress' => 
                object(stdClass)[92]
                  public 'addressId' => string '262862401' (length=9)
                  public 'parentAddressId' => string '262862400' (length=9)
                  public 'confirmedFlag' => string 'Y' (length=1)
                  public 'subAddressType' => string 'Ground Floor' (length=12)
                  public 'subAddress' => 
                    object(stdClass)[91]
                      public 'addressId' => string '417082492' (length=9)
                      public 'parentAddressId' => string '262862401' (length=9)
                      public 'confirmedFlag' => string 'Y' (length=1)
                      public 'subAddressType' => string 'Unit' (length=4)
                      public 'subAddressNumberFrom' => string '7' (length=1)
  protected 'error' => null
  protected 'errorMsg' => null
  protected 'parsed' => boolean false
```

Can someone help me on this query please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the nested subAddress correct? I see you have a subAddress within a subAddress, is this really what you want?

Comment: yes as i have said "subaddress" can be nested nth times, i just need to select the final subaddress types into an array

Comment: A good idea would be to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want? I wrote an example.

```
<?php

class Primary {
    public $postCode;
    public $addressSummary;

    public $subAddress;
}

$primary = new Primary();
$primary->subAddress = new stdClass();
$primary->subAddress->addressId = 1;

$primary->subAddress->subAddress = new stdClass();
$primary->subAddress->subAddress->addressId = 2;

$result = array();
getSubAddresses($primary, $result);

var_dump($result);


function getSubAddresses($obj, &$result)
{
    if ($obj->subAddress)
    {
        $result[] = $obj->subAddress;
        getSubAddresses($obj->subAddress, $result);
    }   
}
```

This will give you addressId 1, and addressId 2, so the two subAddress class.